# how to Click and check the hyper Links in the table columns of webpage

Tags: java, selenium

The webpage contain table with 5 columns.In the fifth column Hyperlinks are there.I would like to click 3rd link matching with name present in first column.

Comment: How about trying smth and share a piece of code?

Comment: This question i had in interview..how to write the Xpath for 3rd link

Comment: Provide more information as: 1. What have you tried still now? Show your code. 2. Where are you stuck? 3. What is the error? 4. Provide the relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: When asking this kind of question you are likely to get better answer if you show you have tried something first, and only then ask for help, showing clearly what you tried and what went wrong. You shouldn't just ask us to do your work for you. See the [help for how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
List <WebElement> rowElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\table1\tr"));

for(int i=1; i< rowElements.size(); i++){

     List <WebElement> colElements = rowElements.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

  for(int j=1; j<colElements.getSize(); j++){ 

   if(colElements.get(j).getText().equals("C")){

    WebElement detail = colElements.get(j+3);

    //detail is your link element; now you can extract what you want from it

   }

 }

}
```